# AlarmService onBoot with interval based on variable

Tags: android, service, boot

Alright so I'm working on a project where I want the app to check the internet for updates. I also want the user to be able to customize how often it makes these checks.

I'm kinda struggling with how I go about doing this.
I'm thinking I have a BroadcastReceiver check for the Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, and then start the AlarmService based upon a variable already set somewhere.

But what happens if the user wants to update the interval? How do I stop the old AlarmService and replace it with the new one?

Also how do I have my AlarmService run a "background update" portion in my app without actually running any of the activities?

EDIT: Also can someone advise if I'm using the AlarmService correctly? I'd want to check for updates fairly frequently, should I be using some other method? I'd check between 1-5 minutes.

Comment: did you mean to update Alarm Interval ?

Comment: Yea. It could be going off every minute, but when the users sets it to two minutes, then it should go off accordingly every two instead of one.

Comment: well in that case , simply close the previous Alarm Settings and open new Alarm Settings with new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a similar thing in my app. I basically have two services: one that sets the alarm and the other that does the actual donwloading.
When your BroadcastReceiver get's the intent ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED you start your alarmService which sends an broadcast to start the downloadService.
So your BroadcastReceiver does both things: starts the alarmServcie if intent == BOOT_COMPLETED else it starts the downloadservice. 
Also if the user changes the periods in which he wants those updates to be done you store the chosen value in the preferences, start the alarmservice and retrieve the values to set up a new period, e. g. 1 hour, 2 hours

Edit: Here is the info some info from the docs about pending Intents and how to cancel them. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

When the user changes the interval you should first cancel your old alarmservice and then set it again.

Comment: What's a pending intent? And do you think I should be using the AlarmService if my intervals are really short? like 1-10 minutes? Also how do I stop the Alarm started in my app?

Comment: First of all here a link for a nice tutorial for setting alarms:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/
I send you a link to the docs. There and in the tutorial you will find instructions on how to cancel your alarm and what a pedingIntet is. And yes, I would use the AlarmService to control my DownloadService. It makes things alot easier in your code and overall appcontrol.

Comment: That tutorial was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm going to try this out in the morning and I'll post any more questions I have.